# PHP checking user inputs. Best Practise?

Tags: php

Hi I was wondering what the best practise for checking user input would be.

I have the code:

```
$currencyConverter = new CurrencyConverter( $_GET['from'], $_GET['to'], $_GET['amnt'] );
```

Would it be best to check the user inputs are valid before sending to the class or should I just write a check in the methods constructor?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would always stick to validating user input early, for one simple fact:

> **You will forget if you leave it off for later**.

Follow that rule, and pass back sanitized input to your models & views.

Answer (score 3):

For all my projects I have introduced a policy to **never ever under no circumstance** use $_GET or $_POST variables in my code.

Instead I have on function such as

```
function get($name, $format) {
    switch ($format) {
#        case 'sqlstring', 'int', 'double', 'htmlstring', 'url', 'path', etc...
    }
}
```

Also, use white-listing whenever possible! If you only can accept three strings, make sure that all other strings validate as false.

Comment: there is `filter_input` for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

The keyword for your purpose is "whitelisting":

You should have a list of all available values per input. And if not every combination is possible, also a list of all allowed combinations.

You might also want to read this article of the OWASP project: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation#Sanitize_with_Whitelist